# Error on Jade iteration ONLY on EC2 instance not locally

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, pug, mean

I have been developing a MEAN app locally on windows and every time I make a change I deploy it to an EC2 linux instance. So far everything is been OK until I added 'iteration on jade' . My dependencies are exactly the same. I double-checked versions and all looks the same locally vs EC2. I've been doing a lot research on stack overflow and google to no avail. Please HELP!

[Screen shot of error on EC2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5CxG.jpg)

[This is how it looks when rendered correctly on my localhost:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4Iq.jpg)

I appreciate your HELP :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any noobie like me get a problem similar to the one I posted above. Make sure that EVERY time you make a BIG change on your node app, especially in data, restart the server. In my case I stopped and restarted FOREVER and that solved the problem. Of course it took me weeks to understand that. I had to create a new app from scratch...add each dependency carefully and get similar errors locally several times....until. It downed on me the need to restart the server to compile the new changes. Duh!
Cheers~~

Happy coding!